# Precision of cdf in scipy.stats

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, precision, cdf

I'm using [chi2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) distribution as a theoretical problem for a simulation system.

For a given interval, I need to estimate this distribution as a PMF defined as the integral of the PDF inside that interval. This value should be near the value of the PDF at the center of the interval, but can be slightly different, depending on the shape of the PDF.

Here is what I do:

```
import numpy
from scipy.stats import chi2

dist = chi2(10)
nbins = 120

F = dist.cdf(numpy.arange(nbins+1))
pmf = F[1:] - F[:-1] # surface inside the interval
pmf /= pmf.sum() # Normalisation
```

The problem is that `chi2.cdf(100, 10)` and above gives exactly 1.0. So the minimum value I'm able to get is around 1.11e-16. But `chi2.pdf(100, 10)` isn't exactly 0 (it's about 2.5e-17).

My question is: how can I get my pmf estimation with greater precision (maybe up to 1e-25)? Why is cdf function less precise than pdf function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

cdf is within floating point precision equal to one, but sf is close to zero, so tiny differences, 1e-20, are not covered up by the big 1. (see JABS reference)

```
>>> probs_from_cdf = np.diff(stats.chi2.cdf(np.arange(nbins+1), 10))
>>> probs_from_sf = np.diff(stats.chi2.sf(np.arange(nbins+1)[::-1], 10))[::-1]
>>> probs_from_sf[:4]
array([ 0.00017212,  0.00348773,  0.01491609,  0.03407708])
>>> probs_from_cdf[:4]
array([ 0.00017212,  0.00348773,  0.01491609,  0.03407708])
>>> probs_from_cdf[-5:]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> probs_from_sf[-5:]
array([  1.94252577e-20,   1.21955220e-20,   7.65430774e-21,
         4.80270079e-21,   3.01259913e-21])
```

I don't know how far the accurate range of the sf, i.e. scipy.special.chdtrc(df, x), goes

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. And in bonus, you showed me the diff function that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 7):

Usually whenever I have a precision problem the first tool I reach for is mpmath.  90% of the time it Just Works(tm), quickly enough.  In this case, we can write:

```
import mpmath
mpmath.mp.dps = 50 # decimal digits of precision

def pdf(x,k):
    x,k = mpmath.mpf(x), mpmath.mpf(k)
    if x < 0: return 0
    return 1/(2**(k/2) * mpmath.gamma(k/2)) * (x**(k/2-1)) * mpmath.exp(-x/2)

def cdf(x,k): 
    x,k = mpmath.mpf(x), mpmath.mpf(k) 
    return mpmath.gammainc(k/2, 0, x/2, regularized=True)

def cdf_via_quad(s,k):
    return mpmath.quad(lambda x: pdf(x,k), [0, s])
```

giving (using your F):

```
>>> pdf(2,10)
mpf('0.0076641550244050483665734118783637680717877318964951605')
>>> cdf(2,10)
mpf('0.003659846827343712345456455812710150667594853455628779')
>>> cdf_via_quad(2,10)
mpf('0.003659846827343712345456455812710150667594853455628779')
>>> F[2]
0.0036598468273437131
>>> pdf(100,10)
mpf('2.5113930312030179466371651256862142900427508479560716e-17')
>>> cdf(100,10)
mpf('0.99999999999999994550298017079470664906667698474760744')
>>> cdf_via_quad(100,10)
mpf('0.99999999999999994550298017079470664906667698474760744')
>>> F[100]
1.0
```

Should be straightforward to use quad to get any normalization you need.